# How to set the swf path of TableTools when using it with Greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey, tabletools

I've been searching for some time now without success, tweaking things in all possible ways I could think about, but with no luck (I must admit I am quite new to this)

I am using Greasemonkey and I would like to save a table to excel or scv.

I've installed Datatables, with all the ressources images and css inside Greasemonkey fine, but I am now stuck with the TableTools install for the export function.

I have these statements in my userscript:

```
// @require     http://datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.js
// @require     https://raw.github.com/DataTables/TableTools/master/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js
// @require     http://www.datatables.net/download/build/TableTools.js
```

And also (which I am not 100% sure about the way of doing it):

```
// @resource    copy_csv_xls    https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools/raw/master/media/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf
```

Then in my code I have

```
    $('#GridView1').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "copy_csv_xls.swf"
        }
    } );
```

I've also tried to set the path using some variable like the following:

```
var copy_csv_xls = GM_getResourceURL ("copy_csv_xls");
```

... with no luck either.

I am getting the followinw error. **EDIT. this error was due to wrong ressource link: I linked to the original  ZeroClipboard repo, whereas it needs to point to the MODIFIED version housed on the TableTools repo (ressource link above changed in the edit)**

```
ReferenceError: ZeroClipboard_TableTools is not defined

var flash = new ZeroClipboard_TableTools.Client();
```

Any clue about this issue ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT (continue)** I had a wrong ressource link (see note above), this partly solved my issues.
However I still seem to have a sSwfPath problem, the following code is about as the closest to something working, but there is still something that doesn't work (no flash plugin showing no action on button click):

```
    $('#GridView1').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": GM_getResourceURL("copy_csv_xls")
        }
    } );
```

Also despite having the ressource set to copy_csv_xls.swf (as opposed to copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf), I have the PDF button showing, which seems a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

If one examines the source code of dataTables.Tabletools.js, while initializing a datatable, tabletools uses the TableTools.DEFAULTS objects and combines them with your tables custom settings.

At line no 1158 , as per the version (1.0.4-Tabletools2) that i have, the code sets the moviePath for ZeroClipboard_TableTools, which i am assuming, is a singleton. Now if you have multiple tables on the page, this object ends up taking the value of swfpath specified for the last table , or Default "sSwfPath":        "../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" , if not specified.

```
    /* Flash file location */
        this.s.swfPath = this.s.custom.sSwfPath;
        if ( typeof ZeroClipboard_TableTools != 'undefined' )
        {
            ZeroClipboard_TableTools.moviePath = this.s.swfPath;
        }
```

So, i changed the order of initialization of the tables on my page as a fix, with the table having the custom path as the last table to be initialized.

Though this fixes the path resolution issue, the buttons are still not working. ! :-(. Hope this helps someone.